# I am trying to push element into two arrays from an object. Returned undefined on the console in the Edge browser

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I am working on an Angular project trying to push element into two arrays from an object. Returned undefined on the console (Edge browser). I did test the same code on the Visual Studio NodeJsConsole project, working fine.

Here is the code,

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this._salesDataService.getOrders()
    .subscribe(res =>{
 
    let data: any [] = [];
    data.push(res);
    
    let months: any [] = [];
    let totals: any [] = [];

    data.forEach(element => {
        months.push(element.Month);
        totals.push(element.totals);
    });


    console.log(data);
    console.log(months);
    console.log(totals);
    });
  }
```

[image: Here is the output]

[image: Output on Visual Studio ...]
Appreciate if someone can help me to figure this out - Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

So there is a key difference in your code here. The VS example that works uses stubbed data (on line 4 of your image). The Angular code is subscribed to `getOrders()`. Inspect the data that comes in (defined for you as `res`) and you'll likely see a difference.

The arrays are not `undefined`, they have 1 element, at index 0, named `undefined`. In other words your code pushed `undefined` into each array, which means your `res` data is not as you expect.

Also your VS code uses `element.Month` and `element.Total` but your Angular code uses `element.Month` and `element.totals` - inconsistent.

Comment: Yes, You are right Haney. Correct code is totals.push(element.total);. What you mean by "res data is not as you expect." Could you please explained a bit? Any direction would be appreciated.

Comment: @SIW you know that your code works with mocked data. So the logical thing to consider is that the subscribed data received from `getOrders()` is not formatted as you expect. Use break points or `console.log()` to print it out!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. Yes it works with mocked data. Data received from the API as json result ( return new JsonResult(table); )  on the console        
(12) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {Month: 'January', Total: 1000}
1: {Month: 'February', Total: 20789}
2: {Month: 'March', Total: 37444}
3: {Month: 'April', Total: 4674}
4: {Month: 'May', Total: 3323}
5: {Month: 'June', Total: 32323}
6: {Month: 'July', Total: 32334}
7: {Month: 'August', Total: 332}
8: {Month: 'September', Total: 23455}  ...........  length: 12    Any thought on this?

Answer (score 0):

From the first screenshot it looks like the result from the service, `res`, is an array. So you're pushing the `res` array into `data` array

Use `res.forEach` instead of `data.forEach`